# Should we stop [sharing] the [share] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, burninate-request

### This is a discussion - not an invitation to go and burninate tags. Please refrain from burninating these tags for now

We have a [share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/share) tag. Here's the tag wiki for that tag:

> questions about sharing resources in (local, and social) networks

It has 4,450 questions as of now*. It can refer to social networks (Twitter, Facebook, etc.). It also is used to mean network shares ([NFS](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bshare%5D+%22NFS%22), [Samba](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bshare%5D+%22Samba%22), etc.)

It can refer to

- Sharing posts on social media - I'm not convinced we need a dedicated tag for this (and if we do, it should be more specific). These should already be tagged with a specific social-media tag (for example, [twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter), [facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook), etc.).
- NFS and/or Samba shares - we have tags for this already ([samba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/samba) and [nfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nfs))
- Finding pieces of data that share some property within a table - we have a [find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/find) tag, although the tag wiki says to not use it
- Sharing files file between devices - we have a [file-sharing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-sharing) that could be used

I propose that we get rid of both the [share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/share) tag and the [sharing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sharing) tag and re-tag as needed (again, don't do this yet - it's only a discussion/proposal for now)

---

*The similar tag [sharing] has 1,213 questions, and there is also 24 questions that are tagged with both the [share] and [sharing]. Those two tags appear to mean the same thing (also, the tag wiki for [sharing] contains "Use tag 'share' instead"). In my opinion, those tags should likely be synonyms.

Comment: A double? Nice!

Comment: I think it can be salvaged, but in its current form both tags are useless. What do social media, file syncing, and network shares have in common aside from the word "share"?